# Django - Manipulate the url before it starts loading

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to remove a part of the existing url of my Website when a user clicks a button. I have an anchor inside a button, but I want to get rid of that to be able to manipulate default url in javascript click handler.

**Here is my code**

```
<tbody>
                        
    {% for stu in st %}
      <tr>

        <td>
        {{stu.id}}
        </td>
        <td>
        {{stu.type}}
        </td>
        <td>
        {{stu.detail}}
        </td>

        <td>
          {{ stu.title }}
        </td>
        
        <td class="td-actions">
        <span class="row mb-3" style="width:8vh;">
        // I know it's wrong to have an anchor inside a button, but how to do that with javascript click handler
          <button class="btn" type="button" id="edit_btn" title="Edit" style="color:white;background-color:#fff;">
            <a href="/data/{{stu.id}}/update">
             <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil fa-2x"></i>
            </a>
          </button>

          <button class="btn" type="button" id="dlt_btn" title="Delete" style="color:white;background-color:#fff;">
            <a href="/data/{{stu.id}}/delete">
             <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash fa-2x"></i>
            </a>
          </button>
          </span>
          
        </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    
  </tbody>
  ... 
  ... 
  ... 

  <script>
    var editBtn= document.getElementById('edit_btn');
    editBtn.addEventListener("click",function(){
      //Here I need {{stu.id}} because I want to remove some part from the default utl before directing to /data/{{stu.id}}/update
    })
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to remove anchor,
you can use "data-*" attributes

```
<button class="btn" type="button" id="edit_btn" title="Edit" 
data-url="your url"
style="color:white;background-color:#fff;">
</button>



 <script>
    var editBtn = document.getElementById('edit_btn');
    editBtn.addEventListener("click",function(event){
       event.preventDefault();
       console.log(editBtn.dataset.url); // you can modify it as you want
    })
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest making following changes:

First, add `data-href` attribute to the button so that we don't need `<a></a>` inside it anymore:

```
<button class="btn" type="button" 
  id="edit_btn" title="Edit"
  style="color:white;background-color:#fff;"
  data-href="/data/{{ stu.id }}/update">
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil fa-2x"></i>
</button>
```

Then in JavaScript read and extract `stuId` from the button tag using simple regular expression:

```
editBtn.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  let url = this.getAttribute('data-href');
  // Assuming every url has same structure:
  let stuId = url.match('^/data/([0-9]+)/')[1];

  // Do other stuff to stuId / url
  // ...

  // Then simulate user click:
  window.location.href = url;
});
```